# Cannot find 'CLKComplicationTemplateExtraLargeCircularView' in scope

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

Hi so I'm building an iOS SwiftUI WatchKit App and I'm getting this error trying to build out
a complication

```
/*

Abstract:

 ComplicationController for Complication UI
*/
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ClockKit

class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    // MARK: - Complication Configuration

    func getComplicationDescriptors(handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> Void) {
        let descriptors = [
            CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier: "complication", displayName: "PushUps", supportedFamilies: CLKComplicationFamily.allCases)
            // Multiple complication support can be added here with more descriptors
        ]
        
        print("getComplicationDescriptors")
        
        // Call the handler with the currently supported complication descriptors
        handler(descriptors)
    }
    
    func handleSharedComplicationDescriptors(_ complicationDescriptors: [CLKComplicationDescriptor]) {
        // Do any necessary work to support these newly shared complication descriptors
        print("handleSharedComplicationDescriptors")
    }

    // MARK: - Timeline Configuration
    
    func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the last entry date you can currently provide or nil if you can't support future timelines
        print("getTimelineEndDate")
        handler(nil)
    }
    
    func getPrivacyBehavior(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with your desired behavior when the device is locked
        print("getPrivacyBehavior")

        handler(.showOnLockScreen)
    }

    // MARK: - Timeline Population
    
    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
        print("getCurrentTimelineEntry")
        handler(nil)
    }
    
    func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int,
                            withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries after the given date
        print("getTimelineEntries")
        handler(nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Sample Templates
    
    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        print("getLocalizableSampleTemplate")
        handler(nil)
    }
    
}


struct ComplicationView: View {
    @Environment(\.complicationRenderingMode) var renderingMode

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            if renderingMode == .fullColor {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.purple)
            } else {
                Circle()
                    .fill(LinearGradient(
                            gradient: Gradient(
                                colors: [Color.white.opacity(0.3),
                                         Color.white.opacity(1.0)]),
                            startPoint: .top,
                            endPoint: .bottom))
            }
            
            Image("coffee_template")
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .complicationForeground()
        }
    }
}

struct CompilcationController_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            CLKComplicationTemplateExtraLargeCircularView(ComplicationView()).previewContext(faceColor: .red)
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing import wise, perhaps something from CLK, I'll update with results.

I was trying to update the watch complication with a view, referencing Apple Docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/building_complications_with_swiftui

Comment: Was Building off of the original Workout Template:

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/build_a_workout_app_for_apple_watch